# SSIS Execute Process task ability to kill children?

Tags: ssis

We are using SQL 2005, and the bundled SSIS.

An Execute Process task is running a standard Windows .BAT batch file.

Inside that batch file, a Java process may be started with something like:

```
%javapath%\java.exe -cp %classpath% com.mycompany.ToDo
```

We put a **TimeOut** value in the task, expecting it to kill the entire task if the job ran too long.

It does appear to terminate the batch file, but not the *child* Java program.

Options, or ways to kill the entire process tree?

Answer (score 0):

If You are willing to write some code, maybe You could have use of these:

[process tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545449/process-tree)

or

[Kill process tree](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/msg/4f423c3d4c59b627)

If You do find solution on the first link, please vote up for both question and answer You used.

Note that code can be utilized from Script Task or You can build an executable program and start it from Execute Process Task.