# C# Get processes opened by other process

Tags: c#, process, system.diagnostics

I'm looking for a way to see if a process starts/triggers other processes.Google chrome is a good example for what i'm looking for:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
p.Start();
```

When starting chrome it will have a PID but it *seems* like this process just triggers other (background) processes and then ends immediately (no PID reference?).

I could assume that any 'chrome' process with a StartTime > p.StartTime could be part of what is triggered but I don't think this is the best way to go. This process could for example start other processes with different names.

Is there a way to 'follow' everything what is triggered from the first process start?

Comment: May be you are interested in something like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/545449/process-tree

Comment: Just snap the Lego pieces together.  [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986856/17034) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2533287/17034).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can P/Invoke [NtQueryInformationProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function to find processes by the parent handles.

Comment: possibly helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394816/how-to-get-parent-process-in-net-in-managed-way