# Change colors in a datagridview depending on the process tree

Tags: c#, visual-studio, datagridview, process

I know how to change the colors of a "Row" in a DataGridView, my difficulty is that, I have to list all the processes that are running (done), but I need to put a different **foreground color** for each **process tree** and without repeting any process on the list, this became quite complicated for me as a beginner, the only thing I found was a method that made my program **extremely slow** here in the *stackoverflow*, if there is any more **optimized** method I would appreciate it.

Here's my old code that only get ths list of processes:

```
private void getProcessList ()
     {
         Process [] processesList = Process.GetProcesses ();

        

         foreach (Process process in processesList)
         {
             double memory = float.Parse (ConvertBytesToMegabytes (process.PrivateMemorySize64) .ToString ());
             memory = Math.Round (memory, 2);

             string processState = "";
             if (process.Responding == true)
                 stateProc = "Active";
             else
                 stateProc = "Does not answer";


             dataGridView1.Rows.Add (process.ProcessName, processState, process.Id, memory + "MB", process.Threads.Count, btnFinalizarProc);
         }
    

         totalProc = processesList.Length;

     }
```

Comment: 'process tree' as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545449/find-the-process-tree-in-net) ? - Also: Is `btnFinalizarProc` relevant and if so how? - Also how shall a tree be converted to a Colors list?

Comment: It is not a list of colors, for example, I have a list with objects of type Color, and for each tree of processes I intend to assign a different color, for example the processes of "chrome", which are several, I wish it had all the same foreground in that "datagridview"

Comment: Also, i know how to do a search for a tree of a process, my dificulty is just the colors to the same process tree

Comment: Well, so you do need a list<Color> and maybe a Dictionary<string, Color>. When the procee's parent is not in the dictionary add it (by name) and assign it a Color, which you then remove from the list. If it is you take its color.. So it is a simple loop over the DGV.Rows with a) finding the process root and b) finding or adding it in/to the dictionary..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the definition of btnFinalizarProc is missing in your code, I have omitted the btnFinalizarProc column in the DataGridView.

You can try to use [Color.FromArgb()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netcore-3.1#System_Drawing_Color_FromArgb_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netcore-3.1) to generate random colors.

And then define a dictionary to store Name_Color key-value pairs

Here is a demo you can refer to.

```
Dictionary<string, Color> name_color = new Dictionary<string, Color>();

private void getProcessList()
{
    Random random = new Random();

    Process[] processesList = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach (Process process in processesList)
    {
        double memory = float.Parse(ConvertBytesToMegabytes(process.PrivateMemorySize64).ToString());
        memory = Math.Round(memory, 2);

        string processState = "";
        if (process.Responding == true)
            processState = "Active";
        else
            processState = "Does not answer";

        // Check if contains
        if (!name_color.ContainsKey(process.ProcessName))
        {
            int int_Red = random.Next(256);
            int int_Green = random.Next(256);
            int int_Blue = random.Next(256);
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(int_Red, int_Green, int_Blue);

            name_color.Add(process.ProcessName, color);
        }

        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
        row.Cells[0].Value = process.ProcessName;
        row.Cells[1].Value = processState;
        row.Cells[2].Value = process.Id;
        row.Cells[3].Value = memory + "MB";
        row.Cells[4].Value = process.Threads.Count;
        row.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = name_color[process.ProcessName];
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getProcessList();
}
```

Test result,

[image]